Unable to parse the results from a webpage using the requests module
I've created a script to scrape the names of the products from this webpage using the requests module. When I run the script, I can see the status code is 200, but the script doesn't bring any results. How can I grab the results from the webpage using the requests module?
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "https://branddb.wipo.int/en/advancedsearch/results?sort=score%20desc&strategy=concept&rows=30&asStructure=%7B%22_id%22:%2262a3%22,%22boolean%22:%22AND%22,%22bricks%22:%5B%7B%22_id%22:%2262a4%22,%22key%22:%22type%22,%22value%22:%5B%22AO%22,%22EMBLEM%22,%22GI%22,%22INN%22,%22TRADEMARK%22%5D%7D%5D%7D&_=1722527941041&fg=_void_&start=0"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'referer': 'https://branddb.wipo.int/',
    'origin': 'https://branddb.wipo.int',
}
res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
print(res.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("span.brandName"):
    print(item.get_text())


Take a look at the page source instead of via inspect on your browser.

I'm guessing it is because you use requests which cannot process javascript.

The page is dynamically loaded, you can use a browser automation tool like selenium or playwright to render the page or better:
You can scrape the API, which returns Base64 AES encrypted responses. In order to decrypt AES you need to install a cryptographic library like PyCryptodome:
pip install pycryptodome

With the API you can get up to 360 entries per request:
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
import base64
import requests
import json


def decrypt(base64_input):
    key = "8?)i_~Nk6qv0IX;2"
    cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_ECB)

    decoded_input =  base64.b64decode(base64_input)  
    decrypted_bytes = cipher.decrypt(decoded_input)
    plaintext = unpad(decrypted_bytes, AES.block_size).decode('utf-8')

    return plaintext


payload = {
    "sort": "score desc",
    "strategy": "concept",
    "rows": 360,
    "start": 0,
    "fg": "_void_",
    "asStructure": json.dumps({
        "boolean": "AND",
        "bricks": [
            {"key": "type", "value": ["AO", "EMBLEM", "GI", "INN","TRADEMARK"]}
        ]
    })
}

url = 'https://api.branddb.wipo.int/search'
response = requests.post(url, json=payload)

decrypted_response = decrypt(response.text)
docs = json.loads(decrypted_response)['response']['docs']

print(docs)


It's an excellent solution. I've got one question on this, though. Could you tell me where you found this key, 8?)i_~Nk6qv0IX;2? Thanks.

@SMTH in the source code, specifically this file. The site uses CryptoJS, by searching that and using the debugger I was able to find the key.

Looks like the content is dynamic.Use selenium instead. If selenium and webdriver-manager not installed Install them.
pip3 install selenium
pip3 install webdriver-manager

Code:
from selenium import webdriver as wb
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Set up Selenium with ChromeDriver
sr = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
dr = wb.Chrome(service=sr)


link = "https://branddb.wipo.int/en/advancedsearch/results?sort=score%20desc&strategy=concept&rows=30&asStructure=%7B%22_id%22:%2262a3%22,%22boolean%22:%22AND%22,%22bricks%22:%5B%7B%22_id%22:%2262a4%22,%22key%22:%22type%22,%22value%22:%5B%22AO%22,%22EMBLEM%22,%22GI%22,%22INN%22,%22TRADEMARK%22%5D%7D%5D%7D&_=1722527941041&fg=_void_&start=0"

# Fetch the content from the link
dr.get(link)

# Wait for the dynamic content to load 
time.sleep(5)

# Get the page source after the dynamic content has loaded
html_content = dr.page_source

# Close the browser
dr.quit()

# Parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
brand_names = soup.select('.brandName')

for brand in brand_names:
    print(brand.get_text())
    

Output:
SFLOORING
MultiMice
MADELEINE PRESS
exia

